# if c|(a+b) and c|(a-b) then c|a?

Tags: divisibility

My professor claims:

> If $c\mid(a+b)$ and $c\mid(a-b)$, then $c\mid a$.

How is this correct? I can't prove it, all I achieved is proving that $c\mid(2a)$ which isn't the same.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:lagrange-multiplier], to [tag:chinese-remainder-theorem], or to [tag:divisor-sum]?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos don't know where these tags came from, sorry :(

Comment: If $c$ is odd, then $c|2a$ does imply that $c|a$. So, any counterexample must have $c=2d$ (even number) with $d|a$ but $c \not\mid a$.

Comment: It not correct if $c$ is even and $a$ and $b$ are both odd.  (Ex: $c = 2$ and $a=7; b=3$).  But if $c$ is odd then it is true by Euclids lemma.  And it will always be true that $\frac c{\gcd(c,2)}$ will divide $a$.  For example if $14|a+b$ and $14|a-b$ then $14|2a$ and so $7|a$.

Comment: They came from you, of course, since you're the one who typed the question.

Comment: Your professor probably meant to claim (or *should* have meant to claim) that if $c$ is odd then.,.....   $2$ and evenness is a pesky little case-checking possibility that frequently sneaks into these time of factorizing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true.

Let $c$ be $2$ and $a=b=1$.

Your conclusion that $c|2a$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true as you point out.

But it does mean that $c|2a$ (and $c|2b$).  And **that** means:

1. If $c$ is odd then $c|a$ and $c|b$.
2. If $c$ is even then $\frac c2|a$ and $\frac c2|b$ (and *maybe* $c|a$ [or maybe not]).